# exec /bin/tcsh produces a "if: Expression Syntax." error

Tags: shell, tcsh, oracle-linux

We have two servers: test box with Oracle Linux 7.6 and production box with Oracle Linux 7.7.

Running the exec /bin/tcsh command produces two different results.

On the test server:

```
# exec /bin/tcsh
#
```

No errors; however, on the production server:

```
# exec /bin/tcsh
if: Expression Syntax.
#
```

We thought that there was an issue with the tcsh package on the production box and uninstalled/re-installed it but doing this did not resolve the issue. Any thoughts/suggestions as to what else we can try to resolve this issue?

One of the comments suggested adding -V to the command. Here are the last few lines of the output:

```
if ( $?QT_PLUGIN_PATH ) then
if ( "${QT_PLUGIN_PATH}" !~ *${libdir}/kde4/plugins* ) then
else

end


if [ ! -d ${HOME}/.local/share -a -w ${HOME} ] then
if: Expression Syntax.
```

There is a test server in which the exec command does not abend. Here's the -V output for the same line above:

```
if ( ! -d ${HOME}/.local/share ) then
```

The only different is the `-a -w ${HOME}`.

Comment: What are the contents of `~/.cshrc` and `~/.tcshrc` ?

Comment: run it as `tcsh -V` and edit the last lines of the output into your question.

Comment: That added bit of output shows exactly [what telcoM says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538331/116858) about `if [ ... ]` tests vs. the `tcsh` syntax for the same test.  It looks as if you have a script written in two incompatible shell dialects.

Answer (score 2):

Such an error message might be caused by a syntax error in the login scripts executed by the `tcsh` shell:

- system-wide `/etc/csh.cshrc`
- system-wide `/etc/csh.login`
- user-specific `~/.cshrc`
- user-specific `~/.login`

In Bourne/POSIX-style shells, the `if` statement is typically `if [ condition ]; then ... else ... fi`, but `csh` and `tcsh` express it as `if (condition) then ... else ... endif`. If you're used to Bourne/POSIX-style scripting, it is easy to type `fi` instead of `endif` when scripting for `tcsh`.

Comment: using `fi` instead of `endif` will not generate that error. you forgot the `~/.tcshrc`.

Comment: Note that the `login` ones would only be run when the shell is started as a login shell, and `exec tcsh` doesn't run `tcsh` as a login shell.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that there is a bug in the kde-settings package. There is bourne-shell code in kde.csh.

We decided to perform the work-around and edited the /etc/profile.d/kde.csh file in the following manner:

original line: if [ ! -d ${HOME}/.local/share -a -w ${HOME} ]

edited line: if ( ! -d ${HOME}/.local/share && -w ${HOME} )

Version-Release number of selected component (if applicable):
kde-settings-19-23.9.el7.noarch

This is the version that is installed on the server. There is an update available, which was not installed, kde-settings-19-23.10. Here's the link to the bugzilla:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1738491.